# Mi VS community no se conecta a MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

Hola no se porque pero no se conecta a mi servidor que tengo en SQL Server

[image: Aqui esta el cuadro de dialogo que aparece al momento de querer hacer la Conexion]

[image: Despues de aceptar no aparece nada]

Ya busque por internet, pero no encuentro la solucion :(

Comment: Dices que buscaste en internet? Cuáles sitios? Cuáles palabras buscaste en google? Cuál tutorial estás siguiendo?

Comment: Has intentado otros drivers? Hay driver especializados para SQL Server.

Comment: Está el servicio de MSSQLSERVER corriendo y aceptando conexiones?